# Set maxValue on Google Material Bar Chart with Multiple Series

Tags: google-visualization, series

I'm enjoying the great [Material chart lib from Google](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart).  I'm wondering if there is a way to set a max value on one of the series when using two independent x-axis?

```
var options7 = {
                bars: 'horizontal',
                series: {
                    0: {axis: 'percent', maxValue: 100}, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'percent'.
                    1: {axis: 'total'} // Bind series 1 to an axis named 'total'.
                },
                axes: {
                    x: {
                        percent: {label: 'Percent Answered', maxValue: 100}, // Bottom x-axis.
                        total: {side: 'top', label: 'Total Questions'} // Top x-axis.
                    }
                },
                hAxis: {title: 'Questions Answered for the Division',  maxValue: 100}
            };
            data7.sort({column: 2});
            chart7 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("deptQuestionsAnswered"));
            chart7.draw(data7, options7);
```

I've added the maxValue field in all the places I thought it might help one at a time, as well as combined (as in above code), but I can't find any documentation on how to do this for multi-series.

Any thoughts?

Comment: there are several configuration options that aren't supported by _Material_ charts, including `maxValue`, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat.  I was hoping that this had been added for multi-series in the meantime but perhaps undocumented.  Still an outstanding library with great potential!  I ended up switching to a classic chart with stacked columns to display what I needed.

Comment: there is an option for classic charts --> `theme: 'material'` -- but still not quite the same...

Comment: Yep, tried that as well... The stacked chart ended up being a winner, and cleaner than the themed one for the data I was presenting, but thank you for the suggestion!